# C# ASP.Net 4 - How to consume third party api post with key/secret?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Being new to Web API, I have been able to create a simple WEB API that receives POST data and save it into database.

But now according to the Third Party API that will be posting data, they have provided some KEY/SECRET. How do I use theses to consume their POST?

Any help understanding this will be greatly appreciated.

Also, how do I restrict the WEB API access to a particular Thrid party API only.

Answer (score 1):

HMAC Authendication - uses a secrect key for each customer which both customer and server know the HMAC hash the message.

Message is built from HTTP request and includes,

- URL
- GET/POST/PUT/DELETE (CRUD)
- Posted Data and the querystring
- DatTime of the request

For EG:
A request is sent to the webserver with a signature HMAC hash

`Host: {host}
 Timestamp: {timestamp}
 Authentication: {username}:{signature}`

GET Request:

`[HTTPGet] /api/values
 User-Agent: Chrome
 Host: example.com
 Timestamp: Tuesday, July 26, 2016 12:39:46 PM 
 Authentication: demouser:LohrhqqoDy6PhLrHAXi7dUVACyJZilQtlDzNbLqzXlw=`

To get the hash signature

`GET\n
 Tuesday, July 26, 2016 12:39:46 PM\n
 /api/values\n`

QUERYString Example:

`[HTTPPost] /api/values?user=demo
 User-Agent: Chrome
 Host: localhost
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Timestamp: Tuesday, July 26, 2016 12:42:6 PM 
 Authentication: demo:LohrhqqoDy6PhLrHAXi7dUVACyJZilQtlDzNbLqzXlw=

To get the hash signature

`GET\n
 Tuesday, July 26, 2016 12:42:6 PM \n
 /api/values\n
 user=demo`

Form data and query string must be the same order to build the proper output.

When a request comes to the server, an authentication filter is implemented to parse the request to get information: HTTP verb, timestamp, uri, form data and query string, then based on these , we build signature using hmac hash with secret key (hashed password) on the server.The secret key is got from database with username on the request.

Then server compares the signature of the request with the signature generated, if equal, authentication is passed, otherwise, it failed.

To build signature:

```
private static string HashSignature(string password, string message)
{
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password.ToUpper());
string hashData;

using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
{
    var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
    hashData= Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}

return hashData;
}
```

To prevent the repeated calls to the server, use the timestamp constraint.

Here the demo https://github.com/thenna/Hmac.WebApi

Comment: Thanks for the above info. The server is running .Net Framework 4.0 and the above example requires 4.5.

Do you have any examples for Web API 1 HMAC ASP.NET 4.0 

Any help is greatly appreciated, struggling to work this out.

Comment: Try this and let me know if its not working out, i will create a new sample and provide you. [link](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/)

Comment: Thanks Thennarasan ... will try out the code in the link and let you know how I go.

Comment: I am running your code, and accessing api "/api/Values" using postman. It authenticates it once but rejects subsequent requests. I can't understand why it is rejecting. How user will renew authentication code ([username]:[hashedstring]) for subsequent requests?